# WebClient gives error when reading .dat file

Tags: c#, silverlight, webclient

The following piece of code is used to read a file from server and download it to the client pc:

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.OpenReadCompleted += (s, e) =>
{
    using (var fs = (Stream) dialog.OpenFile())
    {
           e.Result.CopyTo(fs);
           fs.Flush();
           fs.Close();
    }
 };
 webClient.OpenReadAsync(GetFileUri(fileToDownload));
```

When downloading a .txt file everything is ok. But when I try to download a .dat file I get following exception:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException with inner exception
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.The Uri is relative and doesn't present an issue with the .txt file.

I can't seem to find information if this should be possible or what the issue could be. The error itself also doesn't give me much. Any thoughts?

Comment: Well does the server definitely return the file for that URL? Does it work in a browser?

Comment: When I put the Url in the browser I get this: HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

Comment: Right. So that's the problem - nothing to do with your client code.

Comment: ".dat" is not a default MIME type. You have to configure your web server.

Answer (score 0):

There was a setting missing in the config file. I needed to add the following:

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".dat" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```